# »Pankreatitis« – der oder die?

Tags: gender, duden

Der Duden sagt, *Pankreatitis* sei weiblich. Aber Google Translate zeigt sie/ihn als männlich!

Wem ist zu glauben?

Comment: Until further notice, a manually curated lexicon *always* is better than automatic machine learning. AI has improved, but for such tasks it's still terribly bad, viewed absolutely.

Comment: Lol - Pankreatitis *ist keine Frau* (und auch kein Mann), aber das grammatikalische Geschlecht ist weiblich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine -itis ist eine Entzündung. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_itis) sagt ganz klar, dass eine -itis weiblich ist:

> Grammatik
>   die -itis; Genitiv: der -itis, Plural: die -itiden

Das stimmt übrigens auch mit (meiner Version von) [Google Translate](https://translate.google.de/#en/de/The%20Pancreatitis) überein:

> The Pancreatitis — Die Pankreatitis

Ob es **die** Pankreat**itis** heißt, weil es auch **die** Bauchspeicheldrüsen**entzündung** heißt, weiß ich nicht. Sehr oft wird das Genus von Fremdwörtern ja am Genus der deutschen Übersetzung festgemacht, aber es gibt auch Ausnahmen.

Man sagt z.B. *Der* Track (auf einer CD o.ä.), obwohl es *die* Spur heißt.

Comment: Jap, Diphthonge gelten grundsätzlich als lang: *ai, ei, au, eu, äu.*

Comment: Die Endung "-itis" ist, wie man an dem merkwürdigen Plural
"-itiden" sieht, griechischen Ursprungs.
Fremdwörter aus dem Lateinischen und Altgriechischen
sind so ziemlich die einzige Gruppe von Fremdwörtern,
bei denen sich das deutsche Genus recht konsequent
nach dem Genus in der Ausgangssprache richtet, und nicht,
wie sonst meist, nach dem Genus des übersetzten Wortes
oder der klanglichen Assoziation.
Darum heißt es bspw. in der medizinischen Fachsprache
auch "das Pankreas" ("die Bauchspeicheldrüse"),
"das Virus" ("der Erreger")
und "der Diabetes" ("die Zuckerkrankheit").

Comment: @Uwe zumindest für *Diabetes* gibt es keinen Unterschied (*diabetes mellitus = zuckersüßer Durchfluss*, *Zuckerkrankheit* ist eine Sekundärbezeichnung)

Comment: Jans Kommentar steht da so einsam und zusammenhangslos; ich möchte das mal aufklären: Er hatte in meinem Post "heisst" vs. "heißt" korrigiert. Ich hatte dann freudig angemerkt, dass ich eine hier gelernte Regel (wegen ihrer Klarheit) sehr gut finde: Nämlich, dass "ei" usw. per definitionem laaaang ausgesprochen werden und daher immer von "ß" gefolgt werden und dieser weiss/weiß-Quatsch damit endlich ein Ende hat.

Comment: @PerlDuck Dir ist klar, daß die Rechtschreibreform an dieser Stelle absolut nichts geändert hat, oder? Ein "ss" nach Diphthong war schon immer falsch (oder schweizerisch).

Answer (score 4):

Zuerst mal:

Nicht die Dinge haben ein grammatisches Geschlecht, sondern die Wörter (also die Namen der Dinge). Daher kann die Tunte weiblich sein, obwohl sie ein Mann ist, und das Weib kann sächlich sein, obwohl es biologisch weiblich (sic!) ist.

Daher ist Pankreatitis weder eine Frau noch ein Mann, sondern eine Krankheit. Aber das *Wort* »Pankreatitis« könnte *weiblich*, *männlich* oder *sächlich* sein.

Jetzt die Antwort deiner Frage:

**Jede <*Irgendwas*>-(t)itis ist weiblich.**

Beispiele:

- die Hepatitis (Leberentzündung)
- die Enzephalitis (Gehirnentzündung)
- die Gastritis (Magenentzündung)
- die Arthritis (Gelenksentzündung)

und eben auch

- die Pankreatitis (Bauchspeicheldrüsenentzündung)

Comment: Agreed (with the notable exception _der Fitis_).